# To find repeated matches by `uniq -d`

Tags: uniq

**My data as /tmp/1**

```
9367543
9105616
9108177
8948074
8860323
9170406
9105616
```

I run and I get nothing

```
cat /tmp/1 | uniq -d
```

This is strange, since `uniq -d` should

```
-d      Only output lines that are repeated in the input.
```

**How can you use `uniq -d`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to sort your data before you use uniq. It only removes/detects duplicates on adjacent lines.

Comment: Or use an awk script to do the job properly?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! --- It even says in the manual `The uniq utility reads the specified input_file comparing adjacent lines - -.`

Comment: With my GNU coreutils uniq the manual says:


  Discard  all but one of successive identical lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

Answer (score 1):

Try this to double check, it will output any lines which are duplicated:

```
  cat /tmp/1 |  awk 'seen[$0]++ == 1'
```

Oh, this is your problem:

```
 cat /tmp/1 | sort | uniq -d
```

Sort it before running uniq!

Comment: Lines 2 and 7 of Masi's sample file are the same. But they're not on consecutive lines, which appears to be the heart of the misunderstanding.

Comment: ghostdog, well I am using cat because the OP did also. Yes I am aware I could use shell redirection instead, or give as a command line arg to awk or sort.

dave, thanks. Didn't see that one! edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{_[$0]++}END{for(i in _)if(_[i]>1) print i}' /tmp/1
```

or just

```
awk '_[$0]++ == 1' file
```

Comment: awk '_[$0]++' only works if there is at most one duplicate for each line with duplicates. If you had three rows that were the same, it would print out twice.